# Resize CMD Window

Tags: windows, command-prompt, dos, cmd

How can I resize the Command Prompt window programmatically in C or C++? For example 80x25 or 80x40 characters. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`SetConsoleWindowInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686125%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to set the size of a MS-DOS Prompt in Windows 9x?

Comment: @user964672 The structure of the command prompt in Win9x is completely different to the console subsystem in WinNT derived OSs. It might be possible, but is likely to need low level manipulation: programmatically generating a `.pif` file is likely to be much easier.

Comment: How can I create a .pif file to set the command window to 80x25?

Comment: @user964672 Create two PIF files with the UI differing only in Window size, then compare them. The last Win9x is over a decade old and well out of support: *you are on your own*.

Comment: Is there a way to determine the size of the command window (in WINNT based OSs) without resizing it so the program can adjust the output accordingly?

Comment: @user964672 Follow the link to the Docs... this is covered in the remarks.

Comment: -1 Please consider writing a summary of the link, or an explanation of how the user can use this to solve their problem. A link on its own is not especially helpful and does nothing to help defend against link rot.

Comment: @staticbeast Feed free to expand... adding "Use the ... API" is about as much as I can see. Anything more would be just copying from the linked doc – which needs to be read for important details.

Answer (score 5):

The MODE command allows you to set the size of the Command Prompt window. The syntax is:

```
MODE [COLUMNS],[LINES]
```

For example for a 80x25 window you would use

```
system("MODE 80,25");
```

This size is associated with a specific instance of the window so other command windows will be set to the default size. It works in both newer WinNT based OSs (i.e. Win2000/XP/7) and Win9x. If the size is not supported it will not change.

Place it before any output, as it clears the screen.

Answer (score 4):

I did some more research and this is what I came up with:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
  system("mode 80,25");   //Set mode to ensure window does not exceed buffer size
  SMALL_RECT WinRect = {0, 0, 80, 25};   //New dimensions for window in 8x12 pixel chars
  SMALL_RECT* WinSize = &WinRect;
  SetConsoleWindowInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), true, WinSize);   //Set new size for window

  //Insert your code here

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: system() function may have security problem.
if there is program named 'mode' it will execute the 'mode' instead of resizing cmd prompt