# Limited .exe Output in C++

Tags: c++

I'm sure this is a simple question, but I tried a couple google searches and wasn't sure what keywords to search.

After executing my program in C++ the .exe window that opens is only showing the bottom part of my output, while cutting off the top. Any thoughts on how to view all of my output?

Thank you.

Comment: Resize the command prompt window manually? Or do you want a coding approach?

Comment: You need to provide more information to make your question make sense.   What development environment are you using?

Comment: @DaleWilson, if it's an .exe it's Windows(?), unless OP is just generalizing the term `executable`. Serious question, did you try the scrollbar? (*nix developer... haven't used Windows for programming since 2010... even then I didn't know what I was doing).

Comment: _...the bottom part of my output_ What does that mean?

Comment: You can resize your command prompt in windows http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19982/how-to-make-the-windows-command-prompt-wider/ or via c++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552644/resize-cmd-window. The max lines settings might be what you mean as well.

Comment: Most likely your console only stores `X` lines and you wrote `X + some_amount` so you lose the `some_amount` lines.

Comment: _"I tried a couple google searches"_ You really should be performing substantially more research than a couple of Google searches. What happened to reading and studying?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - they bloody-well "made an app for it". (unfortunately, few use it - or so it seems)

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect the output of the program to a file:

> your-program.exe > file.txt

Alternatively, you can pipe the output into `more`:

> your-program.exe | more

This will pause the output of your program when it fills one screen until you press the space bar.

Both approaches have their pros and cons: if you redirect the output to file and open that file while the program is running, you might not see the last chunk of data, because the OS might buffer the data before writing it to hard disk.
If you pipe the output into `more` then the execution of your program might be suspended while `more` is waiting for your input.

[Edit: incorporated enhzflep's suggestion of using a redirection to a file.]

Comment: Or even, re-directing it into a file for later viewing. `your-program.exe > yourOutput.txt`

Comment: This is probably a better solution than the `more` solution: the output can be viewed in an editor, and, depending on the OS, the program execution might be stopped while `more` is waiting for an input.

Comment: They each have their use. You'll get stuck at a 'press any key to continue' prompt if output is re-directed, since the message is in the file instead of on screen.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have an "a.exe" program

execute　the program like this: 
a.exe >1.txt

and open the file "1.txt" with notepad or other editor(such as notepad++).

Comment: Seriously? If you're going to take a comment and make it your own answer, the least you could do is make some mention of the fact. Unimpressed.